# Show that $\left\{\varphi\in{L^p(\mu)}':f(x)\ge\langle\varphi,f\rangle\text{ for all }f\in L^p(\mu)\right\}=\{\delta_x\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\mu)$ be a measure space and $$\delta_xf:=f(x)\;\;\;\text{for }f:E\to\mathbb R$$ denote the evaluation functional at a fixed $x\in E$ with $\mu(\{x\})>0$. Now let $p\in[1,\infty]$. How can we show that $$\left\{\varphi\in{L^p(\mu)}':f(x)\ge\langle\varphi,f\rangle\text{ for all }f\in L^p(\mu)\right\}\tag1$$ is precisely $\{\delta_x\}$?

Obviously, $\delta_x$ is contained in $(1)$. Moreover, the condition in $(1)$ implies some kind of operator norm bound on the $\varphi$ contained in $(1)$. How can we conclude?

Comment: This does not make much sense. $\delta_x$ is not  well defined function on $L^{p}$ so you cannot consider it as an element of $(L^{p})'$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I've forgot to write down the assumption $\mu(\{x\})>0$. Guess that's what bothered you, right?

Comment: If $\mu \{x\}>0$ then the question  makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you accept my answer ?

Comment: Following what @KaviRamaMurthy said in his comments, the problem has no sense unless you consider elements of $L^p(\mu)$ as *functions* and not *function classes* as it is customary to do: this approach is adopted by a few authors when dealing with the pointwise behavior of weakly differentiable functions.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri Yes, it should be $\mathcal L^p(\mu)$ in the question.

Comment: @DanieleTampieri If $\mu(\{x\}) \ne 0$ then $f(x)= \frac1{\mu(\{x\})}\int_{\{x\}} f d\mu$ is well-defined, where  $f \mapsto\int_{\{x\}} f d\mu$  is always well-defined  and if $\mu(\{x\})=0$ then it is the zero linear map.

Comment: @0xbadf00d If $\varphi$ and $\delta$ are linear maps such that $\forall f, |<\varphi,f>| \le |<\delta,f>|$ what do you get for $\varphi$ ?

Comment: @reuns Then $u=0$.

Comment: hmm ? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @reuns You've edited your comment. If $\delta$ is now an arbitrary linear map, what should I get for $\varphi$?

Comment: you can think to $<\delta,f>=f(0)$ but it doesn't change the problem and solution

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I don't know what you're after.

Comment: $\forall f, |<\varphi,f>| \le |<\delta,f>|$  implies something very restrictive for $\varphi$

Comment: @reuns Could you please tell me what you want to hear?

Comment: a relation between $\varphi$ and $\delta$. The kernel of one linear map contains the other. Projecting $f$ to the kernel isn't difficult.

Comment: @reuns That's what I thought. Well, it obviously tells us that the plot of $\varphi$ is within the strip induced by $\delta$.

Comment: I put the solution in my answer

Comment: @reuns I see (+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a real vector space and $u,v$ two linear maps $X \to \Bbb{R}$.

> If $\forall f \in X, \langle u,f\rangle \ge 0$ then $u = 0$.

Proof : if $u \ne 0$ then for some $f \in X$,$\langle u,f\rangle\ne 0$ so that $\langle u,f\rangle$ or $\langle u,-f\rangle$ is not $\ge 0$.

> If $\forall f \in X, |\langle u,f\rangle| \le |\langle v,f\rangle|$ then $u = C v$ where $C\in [-1,1]$

Proof : take $g\in X,\langle v,g\rangle=1$ then $|\langle u,f-\langle v,f\rangle g\rangle| \le |\langle v,f-\langle v,f\rangle g\rangle|=0$ so that $u= \langle u, g\rangle v$

Comment: Can we apply the same idea to show that if $u(f)\le\max(v(f),w(f)$ for all $f\in X$, then $u=cv+(1-c)w$ for some $c\in[0,1]$?

Comment: Sure take $g_1,g_2$...